# Emulate NFC tag with a static UID on android (ISO 14443-3A)

Tags: android, nfc

I have an ISO 14443-3A card with a static UID and a reader. Does the latest version of Android support simulating acting as the card and transmitting the stated UID? And does such a solution requires root premissions?

I have tried to read about it myself, and read the documentation about `Host-based card emulation` but didn't get very far. I have general development experience and a bit of Android dev, but I want to make sure it's possible before I start creating an app.

Comment: It's not possible, the UID is always random for security purposes.

Comment: @Andrew Why would that be a security feature?

Comment: If the phone gave off a unique number every time it was energised by a reader then it could be used to track you as you moved around the world, this could even been done when the phone was locked and with the right hardware can be done at much greater distances than normal NFC. Also anything just relying on a static UID is totally insecure as they are so easily faked, the UID in NFC was designed only to differentiate between multiple Tags that are in range at the same time.